# add a sub application to IIS express

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-express

Is it possible to add a separate application to the virtual directory in IIS express so that I could have two applications under one domain ?

Thanks

Comment: Then what have you tried? I see no reason that it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a sub-application by  adding an application section in Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

```
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
            <application path="/mysubapp">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\myfolder" />
            </application>
```

[image]

Now you can use a domain for mutiple web apps.